# Rails 4: NoMethodError: undefined method `primary_key' for Hash:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, hash, primary-key

I am using `devise_invitable` to allow `User`s to send invitations, but I get the following error when I try to send an invitation: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'primary_key' for Hash:Class`.  I think it has something to do my my associations, but I'm not sure what I need to provide to fix it.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :invitable

  has_one :client
  after_save :add_client


  def add_client
    self.create_client(user_id: self.id)
  end
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Error:

```
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."invitation_token" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["invitation_token", "c39548b1bad9e023129f341fa5a6abd222f501029eaec8fae60c84e013587e75"]]
NoMethodError: undefined method `primary_key' for Hash:Class
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:571:in `primary_key'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:315:in `association_primary_key'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:83:in `replace_keys'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_polymorphic_association.rb:13:in `replace_keys'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb:14:in `replace'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb:17:in `writer'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:123:in `invited_by='
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise_invitable-1.5.5/lib/devise_invitable/model.rb:126:in `invite!'
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
... 3 levels...
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:180:in `block in serve'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `fork'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:128:in `block in run'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `loop'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application.rb:122:in `run'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/jeremylopez/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in
```

Comment: Can you add a stack trace or something else with more information?

Comment: I added the full error